# How to create an array of several .txt files

Tags: python

I am trying to create some plots from some data in my research lab. Each data file is saved into tab-delimited text files.

My goal is to write a script that can read the text file, add the columns within each file to an array, and then eventually slice through the array at different points to create my plots.

My problem is that I'm struggling with just starting the script. Rather than hardcode each txt file to be added to the same array, is there a way to loop over each file in my directory to add the necessary files to the array, then slice through them?

I apologize if my question is not clear; I am new to Python and it is quite a steep learning curve for me. I can try to clear up any confusion if what I am asking doesn't make sense.

I am also using Canopy to write my script if this matters.

Comment: Here's how to get started: You can  use `os.listdir()` to get a list of all files in a given directory. Alternatively, you could use `glob.glob()` and get a list of just those in the directory that have a certain extension, like `"*.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```py
from csv import DictReader # CSV reader can be used as TSV reader
from glob import iglob

readers = []
for path in iglob("*.txt"):
    reader = DictReader(open(path), delimiter='\t')
    readers.append(reader)
```

`glob.iglob("*.txt")` returns an iterator over all files with extension `.txt` in the current working directory.

`csv.DictReader` reads a CSV file as a iterator of `dict`s. A tab-delimited text file the same thing with a different delimiter.